# Python subprocess - user input from C++ executable

Tags: python, c++, qt, subprocess, qstring

I have a C++ code that I compiled into an Windows executable that runs just fine. When I run it, a console pops up and the user is requested to enter a string (the C++ script actually expects a QString by definition).  The one line in my C++ script that waits for user input is:

```
cout << "OTHER STUFF TO PRINT OUT" << endl;
cin >> input;  //input is a QString here
cout << input.toStdString() << flush;
```

I'm trying to run this executable with Python subprocess and I can't get it to accept an input string. Here's what my python script looks like:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["file.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=FULL_PATH)

for line in proc.stdout: print line

proc.stdin.write("My string")
proc.stdin.flush()
print proc.stdout.readline()
```

The Python script runs correctly (i.e. outputs the right stuff) until it hits the write statement and just hangs there. I have tried many different variations of the above write statement (e.g. communicate, append "\n" to Mystring, etc) to no avail, so I'm reaching out for some help. I have reviewed this site with no luck either.

Comment: The C++ program is reading from stdin before stdout - yet in the Python you are reading stdout first.  Python will block until there is something in stdout, and C++ will block until there is something in it's stdin - which will never happen.  You have to be very aware of the order of operation,

Comment: Yes, indeed, but prior to my cin and cout calls, there's a bunch of cout calls as well that I was not showing here. That's why I have a proc.stdout in my python script. My Python and C++ scripts seem to be working correctly all the way to the stdin.write call...

Comment: I have a suspicion that the QString format of the input is what is causing problem...

Comment: it can't possibly work: `for line in proc.stdout` won't return *until EOF*. What is wrong with `out, err = Popen('file', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate(b"My string")`?

Comment: Good catch! That did it. Popen.communicate doesn't work for me since the stdin.write is in a loop, requesting user input every time. From what I understand, "Popen.communicate" closes the PIPE and I need it to stay open.